# transaction with Transactional and TransactionalTestExecutionListener what is the difference?

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Are there any difference between enabling transaction using `@Transactional` annotation on test class and enabling transaction with test listener `@TestExecutionListeners(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class)`?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/applicationContext.xml")
@Transactional
public class MyTestClass {
....
}
```

and

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/applicationContext.xml")
@TestExecutionListeners(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class)
public class MyTestClass {
....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TransactionalTestExecutionListener` is the only guy who creates transactions. It checks `@Transactional` annotation presence and then opens transaction. In case on test execution listeners are specified spring uses some default test execution listeners one of which is `TransactionalTestExecutionListener`, that is why it seems that listener and annotation works separately.